# calculation sum using value from dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

**I appreciate the help I have gotten so far but to clarify, what I really need is to figure out a way to multiply the tip with the price of the size selected by the user in order to get the total.**

My intro class just started using dictionaries and I don't know how to go about calculating  the total cost in this problem:

Define a dictionary where the keys are the choices of latte (Short,Tall,Grande,Venti) and the values are the corresponding cost (given below).

Traverse the dictionary with a for loop and print the choices and their corresponding price, like this (use the String Format method):

Short latte: $2.10

Tall latte: $2.95

Grande latte: $3.65

Venti latte: $4.15

Ask the user for their choice of size. Then, ask the user to enter a percentage for the tip. Calculate the total cost with the tip. Print the cost in a sentence with the String format method.
This is my rather primitive attempt that is lacking the calculation for the total:

```
def print_dictionary(myDict):
    for key, value in myDict.items():
        print(f"{key} latte: {value}")

myDict = {}
Keys = ['Short', 'Tall', 'Grande', 'Venti']
Values = [2.10, 2.95, 3.65, 4.15]
choice = input('Please choose a size')
tip = float(input('How much would you like to tip?'))
tip = tip / 100 + 1

for key, value in zip(Keys, Values):
    myDict[key] = value
    


print('The total cost is ${}'.format(print_dictionary(myDict)))
```

Comment: It seems that you got a good start, why don't continue and try it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create the keys and values separately.  Just do:

```
myDict = {
    'Short': 2.10,
    'Tall': 2.95
    'Grande': 3.65,
    'Venti': 4.15
}
```

Now, if you have a size, the price is stored in `myDict[size]`.  Just that easy.  You MIGHT consider storing the sizes as lower case, to make it easier on the user, but that's just an extra.

I'm not sure what you're doing to the tip.  Are you assuming they are going to enter a percentage?  If so, you should say that.

Comment: I appreciate the help I have gotten so far but to clarify, what I really need is to figure out a way to multiply the tip with the price of the size selected by the user in order to get the total.

Comment: You didn't say that in the question.  That's just `final = myDict[size] * (1 + tip / 100)`.